# How to preview model record

Tags: octobercms

[Backend]

Click on list item opens Update page. How to preview a record instead?
And I want edit button on the preview page to open Update view.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself... again.
To preview model record instead of update you should edit `Record ul` property in List controller in Builder. Where is `/update/` change it to `/preview/`.